# In the Telerik Report Designer, how do you create a multi-column table with group headers?

Tags: sql, datatable, telerik, crosstab, telerik-reporting

I'm using the Telerik Report Designer (the standalone application, not the one in Visual Studio).  I have a dataset with two fields: group and task.  I'd like to make a table where each group is in it's own column with the tasks for that group listed below.  The best I've come up with is a crosstab report that shows the groups and tasks and their counts, but this isn't what the client wants.  How can I get the results I want in the report designer?  If Telerik controls can't do this, how could I rewrite my SQL query to output the data is the format I want so I can directly use the SQL output to populate a table?

Here is my dataset:
[image]

The query I used to get that dataset is:

```
SELECT 
  tblDtl.Group
, tblDtl.Task
FROM tblHdr
INNER JOIN tblDtl ON tblHdr.CLHId = tblDtl.CLHId
INNER JOIN tblType ON tblHdr.CLHId = tblType.SelectedId
INNER JOIN tblOrder ON tblType.TypeId = tblOrder.Type
ORDER BY tblDtl.CLDDisplayOrder
```

Here is my desired output:
[image]

The best I've gotten is a crosstab that looks like this:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

*** Partial Answer ***

I wasn't able to figure out how to get the 2 columns I wanted, but I used the code below to at least get the header in the first row with the details below it.  I put this code in a stored procedure and then used that stored procedure as the data source for a table within the Telerik report.

```html
CREATE TABLE #Checklist
(
 Checklist varchar(200),
 Notes varchar(50)
)


SET NOCOUNT ON;  

DECLARE
 @HeaderName varchar(200),
 @GroupName varchar(200),
 @TaskGroupName varchar(200),
 @TaskDesc nvarchar(200)

DECLARE header_cursor CURSOR FOR   
SELECT DISTINCT tblCheckListHdr.CLHName, tblCheckListDtl.CLDGroupName
 FROM tblCheckListHdr
 INNER JOIN tblCheckListDtl ON tblCheckListHdr.CLHId = tblCheckListDtl.CLHId
 INNER JOIN tblServiceType ON tblCheckListHdr.CLHId = tblServiceType.SelectedCLHId
 INNER JOIN tblWorkOrder ON tblServiceType.ServiceTypeId = tblWorkOrder.ServiceType
WHERE tblWorkOrder.WorkOrderId = @WOid
 AND tblCheckListHdr.CLHActive = 1
ORDER BY tblCheckListDtl.CLDGroupName

OPEN header_cursor 

FETCH NEXT FROM header_cursor INTO @HeaderName, @GroupName

WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0  
 BEGIN  

 INSERT INTO #Checklist (Checklist, Notes)
 SELECT @HeaderName + ' | ' + @GroupName, 'Y, N, NA, Notes' AS Notes

  DECLARE detail_cursor CURSOR FOR   
  SELECT tblCheckListDtl.CLDGroupName
   , tblCheckListDtl.CLDTaskDesc
  FROM tblCheckListHdr
  INNER JOIN tblCheckListDtl ON tblCheckListHdr.CLHId = tblCheckListDtl.CLHId
  INNER JOIN tblServiceType ON tblCheckListHdr.CLHId = tblServiceType.SelectedCLHId
  INNER JOIN tblWorkOrder ON tblServiceType.ServiceTypeId = tblWorkOrder.ServiceType
  WHERE tblWorkOrder.WorkOrderId = @WOid
   AND tblCheckListHdr.CLHActive = 1
   AND tblCheckListDtl.CLDActive = 1
   AND tblCheckListDtl.CLDGroupName = @GroupName
  ORDER BY tblCheckListDtl.CLDDisplayOrder

  OPEN detail_cursor  
  FETCH NEXT FROM detail_cursor INTO @TaskGroupName, @TaskDesc

  WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0  
  BEGIN  

    INSERT INTO #Checklist (Checklist)
    SELECT @TaskDesc

   FETCH NEXT FROM detail_cursor INTO @TaskGroupName, @TaskDesc

  END

  CLOSE detail_cursor  
  DEALLOCATE detail_cursor  
  FETCH NEXT FROM header_cursor INTO @HeaderName, @GroupName
 END   
CLOSE header_cursor;  
DEALLOCATE header_cursor

SELECT #Checklist.Checklist, #Checklist.Notes
FROM #Checklist
```

Answer (score 0):

this can be achieve using [PIVOT](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177410(v=sql.105).aspx), Something like this.

```
IF ( OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#tmpDB') IS NOT NULL )
    BEGIN
        DROP TABLE  #tmpDB
    END


SELECT  testing ,
        production
INTO    #tmpDB
FROM    ( 


            SELECT 
              tblDtl.GROUP [group]
            , tblDtl.Task [task]
            FROM tblHdr
            INNER JOIN tblDtl ON tblHdr.CLHId = tblDtl.CLHId
            INNER JOIN tblType ON tblHdr.CLHId = tblType.SelectedId
            INNER JOIN tblOrder ON tblType.TypeId = tblOrder.Type
            ORDER BY tblDtl.CLDDisplayOrder




        ) P PIVOT ( MAX(task) FOR [group] IN ( testing, production ) ) PVT;
WITH    CTEtesting
          AS ( SELECT   ROW_NUMBER() OVER ( ORDER BY testing ) ctr ,
                        testing
               FROM     #tmpDB
               WHERE    production IS NULL
             ),
        CTEProduction
          AS ( SELECT   ROW_NUMBER() OVER ( ORDER BY production ) ctr ,
                        production
               FROM     #tmpDB
               WHERE    testing IS NULL
             ),
        CTE
          AS ( SELECT   testing ,
                        production
               FROM     CTEProduction P
                        FULL JOIN CTEtesting T ON T.ctr = P.ctr
             )
    SELECT  *
    FROM    CTE
```

Result:

```
testing              production
-------------------- --------------------
Add object           Prompt for input
Report object        Show error log
Show error log       Show report
Vaidate object       Validate input
Validate report      Validate object
Vanipulate object    NULL

(6 row(s) affected)
```